# How to add Windows 7 Jump Lists to a application

Tags: winforms, windows-7, jump-list

I want to add custom jump list entries to my application in Windows 7.

The menus I am referring to are the following.

1. Pin a application to the taskbar.
2. Now right click on the application.
3. Some applications like windows media player etc. have custom options that you can run.

How do I go about adding these to my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows Team Blog has some articles about Jump Lists and other new Windows 7 Shell features:

- Developing for the Windows 7 Taskbar – Jump into Jump Lists – [Part 1](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/archive/2009/06/22/developing-for-the-windows-7-taskbar-jump-into-jump-lists-part-1.aspx), [Part 2](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/archive/2009/06/25/developing-for-the-windows-7-taskbar-jump-into-jump-lists-part-2.aspx), [Part 3](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/archive/2009/07/02/developing-for-the-windows-7-taskbar-jump-into-jump-lists-part-3.aspx)

Those are geared towards C++ applications, there are also [managed code APIs](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/archive/2009/05/18/windows-7-managed-code-apis.aspx) which package those in a way a little easier accessible to .NET developers.

Answer (score 1):

For .Net code, there are some good example and libraries in the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)

The Samples\Shell\TaskbarDemo specifically deals with the TaskBar APIs and shows how to do Jump Lists and control the icon.

Not sure if it has any examples of custom actions like Media Player.