# How to use Windows 7 Jump Lists in a Java Desktop app?

Tags: java, swing, windows-7, jump-list

As the title suggests, we have a Java (Swing) desktop application, and we'd like to be able to have some basic access to the Jump Lists (in the new Windows 7 taskbar).

In particular, we'd like to be able to add some "user tasks" to the jump list--the ability to start other modules in our application, maybe to close all running modules, etc.

I know that we could do this using JNI or JNA and the C API [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409487/how-to-add-windows-7-jump-lists-to-a-application), but that is our option of last resort.  I'm hoping that there might be an easier way--something that Sun has already implemented, or maybe a third party library or something.

Google is no help so far.   Anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Java library providing the new Windows 7 features for Java. It's called [J7Goodies](http://www.strixcode.com/j7goodies/) by [Strix Code](http://www.strixcode.com). You can create your own jump lists with it. Of course it supports "users tasks" too.

Answer (score 1):

This would break compatibility with other systems so Sun almost certainly won't do it.

There are a handful of desktop/toolbar integration libraries out there that make the jni calls for you, you might look for one of those that has been updated for windows 7, but if you are going to go single-platform, why not use C#? (Not that I'm a fan, I'm 100% Java, but if you're already breaking compatibility you might consider going all the way just for ease of programming)

Comment: Well, we are multiplatform, but we try to make some concessions for each platform (i.e. at runtime, we detect which platform we are running on, and do a few "extras" for that platform where possible.)

Comment: Also, our app has been under development for almost 10 years now, so it's a little late to try it in a new language! :)

Comment: Good points, then I guess you are already used to some level of desktop integration--I'd just look at existing products or possibly even find an open source one and extend it yourself--they are all going to do the same thing (JNI call) anyway.

Comment: OS X useds a similar approach with Dock menus, and Gnome 3 is doing something similar, so I don't think it has to do with multi-platform. It's just that it is not ready yet.