# Taskbar right click application context menu [JumpList]

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, taskbar

How can I make a menu on the right click in the taskbar using Windows forms?

Something like this:

[image: Mozilla Thunderbird menu]

Comment: this is called a "jump list". Search with these words to yield better results.

Comment: I will search, thanks @kennyzx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add Windows 7 Jump Lists to a application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409487/how-to-add-windows-7-jump-lists-to-a-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add contextMenuStrip from toolbox to  form1. then go to form1 propertires -> contextMenuStrip . and the select the recently added contextmenuStrip1. You can add buttons to the contextMenustrip.

You should add at least one button in order to get the menustrip on rightclick.

Comment: Are you sure that contextmenustrip will work? I already have a contextmenustrip in my main form and it is not appearing like a 'taskbar' menu.

Comment: you have to use context menu strip but not like the answer.  I have make it before . I will give you the new code.

Comment: I didnt find the code in my computer. but this the link I used.

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/03/Add-System-Menu-Items-to-WPF-Window-using-Win32-API

Comment: I'm grateful for your help, but I'm using winforms not WPF.Anyway I think it will help me.

Comment: @user3471633: That's not the same menu. You're describing the context menu that appears when right clicking the icon in the top left corner of an application. The OP asks about the menu that appears when right clicking an icon in the taskbar in Windows 7 or 8.

Comment: That last link is not helpful either. That describes the menu that is displayed on a *tray icon*, which is not the same as the *taskbar icon*.

Comment: I have found a nice link on stackoverflow 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478089/adding-items-to-the-taskbar-application-menu